lib directory is not created after do_install
I was trying to build hello.bb for test.
In hello.bb, I wrote do_install like below
do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 hello ${D}${bindir}
  
    install -d ${D}/lic
    install -d ${D}/lib
    install -d ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system
    install -m 0644 hello.service ${D}${systemd_unitdir}/system
}

I expeted lib directory created in build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/hello/1.0-r0/image.
but I found only usr, lic directory in build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/hello/1.0-r0/image directory.
Please explaine the reason.

What is the content of build/tmp/work/core2-64-poky-linux/hello/1.0-r0/temp/run.do_install ?

I found the reason.
In DISRO_FEATURES, systemd must be appended.
Thanks
